# Stm32F101 USART receive interrupt invalid state

Tags: c, arm, stm32f4

i am working on an StmF101C816 who uses USART2 for USB communication.
Communication works properly until suddenly i cant get data from the device.

I use a receive interrupt and got an problem that always when i send data via usb the USART2->SR gave me 0xF4 and the USART2->DR gave me 0xF8.

Whatever i send over USB SR and CR are always the same.
The only thing that solves this problem is a erase and reflash of the chip.
After this communication works as expected.

Could this be duo to a stackoverflow or does someone has experience with such a behaviour?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: To minimize wear-out, did you try to reset or power-cycle your device instead of erase and reflash? -- "_After this [erase and reflash of the chip] communication works as expected._" Does it mean that the error is gone then? -- A URL or excerpt of the data sheet about the UART and the meaning of the registers' bits would be helpful.